# Use roscore, roslaunch and rosrun in bash script

Tags: roslaunch, bash, script, roscore, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!
I want to start roscore and several ros nodes from a other program with a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
source /catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
roscore
```

when I call the script manually everything works, but when i call it from the other program (with system(start_ros.sh)) nothing happens.
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233078/use-roscore,-roslaunch-and-rosrun-in-bash-script/) by [mitch1993](https://answers.ros.org/users/26719/mitch1993/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2016-04-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved it by exporting my ros path in the bash script!

---

Originally posted by [mitch1993](https://answers.ros.org/users/26719/mitch1993/) with karma: 46 on 2016-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [felixcra](https://answers.ros.org/users/33766/felixcra/) on 2018-05-10**:
Also don't forget to to source setup.bash in your script.